# How to apply condition on column in SQL grouping in rails 3.2?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

Here are the columns in payment table:

```
user_id, amount, paid (boolean)
```

In rails, we can do SQL grouping as following:

```
grouping = Payment.all(:select => "sum(amount) AS total", :group => "user_id")
```

Our question is in the SAME SQL, how to sum the total for the payment which was paid? Here is what we want to do in pseud code:

```
grouping = Payment.all(:select => "sum(amount) as total, sum(amount if paid) as total_paid", :group => 'user_id')
```

We need to do those two sum in `ONE` SQL. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get total amount payed by a user?

**one way**

in `payment.rb`

```
scope :paid_payments, where(paid: true)
```

in `controller`

```
user.payments.paid_payments.sum(:amount)
```

should return you a sum of all selected payments.

**another way:**

in `user.rb`

```
has_many :paid_payments, class_name: "Payment", :conditions => {:paid => true}
```

in `controller`:

```
user.paid_payments.sum(:amount)
```

Comment: We need both total and total_paid. Is there way to have them in one sql?

Comment: what you mean total and total_paid? do you have a total_paid field as well?

Comment: total and total_paid are the sum of amount